# How to compress height and width of a photo during the time of upload [asp.net]

Tags: asp.net

I want to compress the uploading photo to size `Height =600px & Width= 800px` [only if actual size is greater than this] during the time of upload.photos are saving on `sql server2008` with a datatype image !

```
 public byte[] imagetoByte()
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                int imageFilelength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] ph = new byte[imageFilelength];
                HttpPostedFile ima = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                ima.InputStream.Read(ph, 0, imageFilelength);
                return ph;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

         }
```

function is used for image upload !! somebody help me to fix this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution can be as:

```
int imageFilelength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
byte[] ph = new byte[imageFilelength];

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ph);
Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

//Call function to resize 
Image ResizedImage = RezizeImage(img, 500, 500);

//Save Image
ResizedImage.Save("IMAGELOCATION.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

---

```
private Image RezizeImage(Image img, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    if(img.Height < maxHeight && img.Width < maxWidth) return img;
    using (img)
    {
        Double xRatio = (double)img.Width / maxWidth;
        Double yRatio = (double)img.Height / maxHeight;
        Double ratio = Math.Max(xRatio, yRatio);
        int nnx = (int)Math.Floor(img.Width / ratio);
        int nny = (int)Math.Floor(img.Height / ratio);
        Bitmap cpy = new Bitmap(nnx, nny, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(cpy))
        {
            gr.Clear(Color.Transparent);

            // This is said to give best quality when resizing images
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            gr.DrawImage(img,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, nnx, nny),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return cpy;
    }

}
```

Comment: Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);                                                                                                  statement is showing error... says "the Parameter is not valid"..!!

Comment: I reckon you figured out the problem. vote up if this answer helped you. Thanks